# ERROR: 'Series' object has no attribute 'astypes'. while changing data types of DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to convert the data type of object to string so i can extract the last 4 digits and put it in new column. there is no syntax error in my code but i an getting "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'astypes'". below is the code correctYear is the new column that i want to store the year from the existing column.

i hope you can help me with this as i spent half an hour trying to go around it. thank you.

`df["correctYear"] = df["released"].astypes(str).str[:4]`

this is the output:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [36], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df["correctYear"] = df["released"].astypes(str).str[:4]

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:5575, in NDFrame.__getattr__(self, name)
   5568 if (
   5569     name not in self._internal_names_set
   5570     and name not in self._metadata
   5571     and name not in self._accessors
   5572     and self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name)
   5573 ):
   5574     return self[name]
-> 5575 return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'astypes'
```

I have tried to separate the cod and do the data type change first. it didn't give back any error but the data type didn't change. `df["released"] = df["released"].astype(str)`

Answer (score 1):

It is [`pd.Series.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html)

Try:

```
df["correctYear"] = df["released"].astype(str).str[:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to do is to extract the year part from the dates. I think there might be a better way to do this. First, convert the the dates from string format to datetime format as follows:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(date_strings)
```

Then you can access the year part by doing:

```
dates.dt.year
```

This will give you the year directly.